# how to use transform class with active pseudoclass in tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to give click effect to a button like this:

```
.btn-translate-effect {
    transition: transform .1s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-translate-effect:active {
   transform: translateY(3px);
}
```

with tailwind utility classes.

But I'm not able to it figure it out. I tried this:

```
<button class="transform active:translate-y-4"></button>
```

It doesn't work. I also modified variant config `tailwind.config.js` like this:

```
variants: {
  extend: {
    transform: ['active']
  },
}
```

But to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `transform` with `translate` on tailwind config.

```
  variants: {
    translate: ['active'],
  },
```

[Working Example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RRPUTFvDP7)